# how to include mutliple threading in this script

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I am working on a project which includes two main processing, I have tried using timer_tick to handle the processing which makes the application really slow. The application needs to be running at all times, I wanted the timer aspect of the timer_tick to trigger the methods every X seconds but with the multiple threading, as this makes it a lot faster.

Can anyone help?

The current structure of the application is below:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setting_info();
    }

    public void setting_info()
    {
        // takes data from config file for API connections
    }

    private void swis()
    {
        // connects to API and fetches data
        // need to be continuously running - Ideally Interval(1200)
    }

    private void st_processing()
    {
        // processes the data that was fetched in swis() slows down the program without multiple threading
        // need to be continuously running - Ideally Interval(800)
    }

    private void alert_in_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        while (alert_in == true)
        {
            swis();
            break;
        }
    }

     private void st_processing_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (st_processing == true && alert_data_database_has_data == true)
        {
            st_processing();
            //check_error_count();
            alert_data_database_has_data = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know threading makes it faster if you haven't tried? Are you just asking how to start a thread function or how to get it to talk to a GUI?

Comment: Fair comment about the speed. I have used something like this  ThreadStart threadstartswis = new ThreadStart(swis);
                Thread thread = new Thread(threadstartswis);
                thread.Start(); which I believe starts the thread, however I am having trouble repeating the thread like a timer_tick say every second.

Comment: Can you change the question to show a smaller example including what you have tried, and tell us what went wrong you had "trouble repeating the thread"?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to know. There are many good threading tutorials for C# as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177488/c-sharp-threading) for example [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Starting a thread is easy

```
Thread worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(swis));
//...
worker.join();
```

You will need to be careful if you need to update the GUI as a result of what the thread does. Previously discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c).

At the moment you break from the `alert_in_timer_Tick` once it's called the `swis` function.

```
while (alert_in == true)
{
    swis();
    break;// why is this here?
}
```

Comment: In swis a query is called, once a match is correct it breaks, I will change the question on provide more detail. Thanks.